# Script in C shell skipping over last else statement?

Tags: shell-script, debugging, csh

This is a C shell script that checks the number of arguments and if the file/directory exists. When the arguments are valid, it should go to the last else statement and print "hi", but when I run this script with the correct arguments it doesn't print anything. (but the exit status is 0)
Everything else works fine when I have invalid arguments.

```
if ($#argv != 2) then
        echo "Two arguments required"
else
        if (! -f $argv[1]) then
                echo "File does not exist"
                exit 1
        else
                if (! -d $argv[2]) then
                        echo "Not a valid directory"
                        exit 2
                endif
        endif
else    
        echo "hi"
endif
```

Maybe it's my syntax that is wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: You have two consecutive else statements, how would you expect this to work?

Comment: Yes, your syntax is wrong... `if .. else .. *else* .. endif`? the shell shouldn't even accept that.

Comment: Well, your first mistake was writing `#!/bin/csh`.  [It's all downhill from there.](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Answer (score 1):

This `else` case can't be reached, since you already have an `else` case for this `if`.  What you want to accomplish could e.g. be done the following way:

```
if ($#argv != 2) then
    echo "Two arguments required"
    exit 1
else if (! -f $argv[1]) then
    echo "File does not exist"
    exit 1
else if (! -d $argv[2]) then
    echo "Not a valid directory"
    exit 2
endif

echo "hi"
```

Comment: Please expand. As it is, you are simply stating the obvious which has already  been mentioned twice in the comments. If you want to make an answer out of it, please show a working script that can help the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and didn't look at the comments. :/

Comment: Much better, thanks! And posting an answer from info in the comments is fine, comments are fair game. Just if you do so, expand on it :)